# range-based for loop and std::transform with input/output iterators not equivalent when applied to rows of opencv Mat(rix)

Tags: c++, opencv, for-loop, stl, iterator

In a larger program, I came across the following problem, which I do not understand.

Basically, I am processing an opencv matrix of type float (`cv::Mat1f`) (docs [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/df/dfc/classcv_1_1Mat__.html)). OpenCV provides iterators to iterate over a matrix. When I iterate over the matrix using range-based iterators and a reference to the matrix members, the code works (`test1` in the example below).

When I use `std::transform` and apply it to the *entire* matrix, the code below (`test3`) also works.

However, when I do the iteration row-wise, then the version with `std::transform` fails (it never (?) terminates).

(The reason I work on rows is that in the real application rows are processed in different parallel threads, but that is of no concern here)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

void test1(cv::Mat1f& img) {
    for (int r = 0; r < img.rows; r++)
        for (auto& v : img.row(r))
            v = v+1;
}

void test2(cv::Mat1f& img) {
    for (int r = 0; r < img.rows; r++)
        std::transform(
            img.row(r).begin(),
            img.row(r).end(),
            img.row(r).begin(),
            [](float v)->float { return v+1; });
}

void test3(cv::Mat1f& img) {
        std::transform(
            img.begin(),
            img.end(),
            img.begin(),
            [](float v)->float { return v+1; });
}

int main() {
    auto img = cv::Mat1f(5, 5, 0.0);

    int i = 0;
    for (auto &v : img)
        v = i++;

    std::cerr << img << "\n";

    test1(img);

    std::cerr << img << "\n";

    // test2(img); does not work
    test3(img); // works !

    std::cerr << img << "\n";
}
```

On my system (with opencv installed in `/usr/local`) I run the example code above with

```
g++ -std=c++17 -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 mwe.cpp -L/usr/local/lib  -lopencv_core && ./a.out
```

What is wrong with the code in `test2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call to `row` creates a new object, and these objects have distinct iterators.
So, `row(r).begin()` will never be equal to `row(r).end()`.

Get the iterators from the same object instead:

```
void test2(cv::Mat1f& img) {
    for (int r = 0; r < img.rows; r++)
        auto row = img.row(r);
        std::transform(
            row.begin(),
            row.end(),
            row.begin(),
            [](float v)->float { return v+1; });
}
```